# How can I run an external command with parameters?

Tags: c#, command-line

Convert

```
%systemroot%\system32\dism.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:%systemdrive%\temp\IE-Win7.CAB /quiet /norestart
```

I tried this, but it isn't working.

```
runProgram("dism.exe", "\"" + workingDir + "/Online /Add-Package \\IE-Win7.CAB\" /quiet /norestart /log:\"" + LogFolder + "\\IE-Win7.CAB.evtx\"");
```

Below is just an example program that I am working with has this line that also logs it.

```
runProgram("wusa.exe", "\"" + workingDir + "\\Windows6.1-KB2882822-x86.msu\" /quiet /norestart /log:\"" + LogFolder + "\\Windows6.1-KB2882822-x86.evtx\"");
```

**Background**

The program basically call .msu files to be installed and logs the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sys_root = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("systemroot");
var dism_path = $"{sys_root}\system32\dism.exe";

var sys_drive = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("systemdrive");

var args = $"/Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:\"{sys_drive}\temp\IE-Win7.CAB\" /quiet /norestart"

var proc = Process.Start(dism_path, args);
```

This expands the environmental variables you used in the original call, uses C#6 interpolation syntax to insert them into two strings that can be passed to Process.Start(string, string), to execute the line. Don't want to actually test this myself, of course.